# Javascript recursion with return statement and without

Tags: javascript, recursion, indexing, numbers, return

Is there a difference between these two recursive functions? One with a return statement and one without it for the recursive calls. They both print numbers 1 - 8 in the console browser, my questions is whether there is some optimization happening under the hood when the recursion takes place with a return vs without one.

```js
const solution = (input, i = 0) => {
  if (i === input) return // base case
  console.log(i)
  return solution(input, i + 1) // return recursive call
}

const solution2 = (input, i = 0) => {
  if (i === input) return // base case
  console.log(i)
  solution2(input, i + 1) // recursive call
}

console.log(solution(4))
console.log("----")
console.log(solution2(4))
```

Comment: why don't you run them and see the difference yourself

Comment: I believe every function has an implicit return so speaking that way there's no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the final recursive call doesn't return anything (like in the example in your question), then there's no difference.

If the final recursive call *does* return something, and you want that to percolate up to the initial caller of `solution`, then you *do* need to return the recursive call:

```js
const solution = (input, i = 0) => {
  if (i === input) return 'returnVal' // base case
  return solution(input, i + 1) // return recursive call
}

const solution2 = (input, i = 0) => {
  if (i === input) return 'returnVal' // base case
  solution2(input, i + 1) // recursive call
}

console.log(solution(9))
console.log("----")
console.log(solution2(9))
```

ES6 [does specify](https://2ality.com/2015/06/tail-call-optimization.html) that a recursive function whose final action is to `return` a call to itself should result in the recursive call *without* growing the call stack. If implemented, this would mean that, for example, a function that recursively calls itself 100,000 times before resolving could run successfully, without overflowing the stack. (Without tail call optimization, such a situation would result in a stack overflow.)

But, unfortunately, as you can see from the link above, despite being part of the specification, it's not widely implemented, so the optimization you're hoping for doesn't exist in practice in most environments.

Comment: *not widely implemented* - i.e. only Safari and IOS browser (mobile) and a couple of obscure server runtimes have implemented it

Comment: @JaromandaX Jup. Even after 6 years there is no complete implementation of ES6 / ES2015 just a couple that are close. That also means ES2016-ES2019 have no implementations either since they all rely on ES2015.